# Do unix domain sockets support reuse?

Tags: apache-httpd, unix-sockets, reverse-proxy

Do unix domain sockets support reuse?

Lots of conflicting information about this online. I suspect a lot of it is just outdated, but I'm no expert.

Do I `ProxySet enablereuse=on` if my handler is a socket? e.g.

```
<Proxy "fcgi://matching-worker-string/" max=10>
    # Unsure about this:
    ProxySet enablereuse=on
</Proxy>

<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
        SetHandler proxy:unix:/run/php/php.sock|fcgi://matching-worker-string/
    </If>
</FilesMatch>
```

Many [comments online](https://z-issue.com/wp/apache-2-4-the-event-mpm-php-via-mod_proxy_fcgi-and-php-fpm-with-vhosts/#comment-6765) state that [they're not supported](https://serverfault.com/a/828687/13941), and state you can even check the [Apache docs for proof](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html#examples), but I don't see it. Maybe they didn't have reuse support in 2015-2017, but do now?

**Edit**

Apache 2.4, php-fpm 7.3, mod_proxy_fcgi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your linked answers directly quotes the [apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html) for mod_proxy_fcgi.  According to the answer it states:

> UDS does not currently support connection reuse

But this phrase no-longer exists in the documentation.

It was there when the answer was written on [26 jan 2017](https://web.archive.org/web/20170127134950/http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html).  The first snapshot on waybackmachine where it was removed is [10 Aug 2017](https://web.archive.org/web/20170810162258/http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html).

I haven't managed to find reference to this being "fixed" in the commit history.  The statement was removed from the documentation in [SVN commit 1802336](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1802336) AKA [git commit 2a3f6ec2](https://github.com/apache/httpd/commit/2a3f6ec221f5eeebc6ac1acb0623b500ef5c0841)  simply with the comment:

> UDS does support reuse
>
> jimjag

### Conclusion

`mod_proxy_fcgi` does support connection reuse for unix domain sockets.  ...Not withstanding any unreported bugs.